# How to perform operation on subdocuments without fetching a parent in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For now in case I want to remove a subdocument I do this:

```
Post.findById(post_id).exec(function(err, post) {
  post.comments.remove({'_id': comment_id});
  post.save(function(err) {
    res.end("Hooray!");
  });
});
```

Which seem to be non-optimal to me, because each time I remove a comment the whole post will be fetched from DB and it has a lot of stuff attached to it. So, is it possible to modify subdocuments without fetching a parent document?

Comment: yes by putting post and comments on 2 separated documents ... otherwise no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) if you want to update document without fetching it, you have to perform update request manually. In my case it will result in this code:

```
Post.update({'_id': post_id}, {$pull: {'comments': {'_id': comment_id}}}).exec(function(err){
  console.log('Hooray!');
});
```

It is a good workable solution, but performing direct request means that validations wouldn't work as well as versioning.